# Parse nested yaml with Haskell

Tags: haskell, yaml

How would one define a type for the following yaml configuration:

```
request: 
  a: "https://google/1"
  b: "https://google/2" 
  c: "https://google/3"
```

Would it be like this?

```
data Config = Config { request :: id' } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

and then define `id'` later?

Comment: Is the `yaml` embedded here, or a file you plan to read in each time you use the application. In case of the latter, you will need some `IO` here to parse the file. In case of the former, you can use *quasiquoters* or template haskell to parse it.

Comment: It's a file I plan to read in each time

Comment: @timothyylim Will `request` always have `a`, `b`, `c` with string values every time you read the file? Or can `request` change arbitrarily?

Comment: a,b,c can be arbitrarily changed

Comment: In that case @timothyylim would `data Config = Config { a :: Value, b :: Value, c :: Value }` be suitable? (where `Value` comes from the `yaml` library)

Comment: My apologies, what I meant was that “a” may be an arbitrary string and so may it’s value

Comment: So then is there any reason why `data Config = Config { a :: String, b :: String, c :: String }` wouldn’t work?

Comment: Because the yaml may be: d: “xxx” e: “www” etc

Comment: So more like `newtype Config = Config { Map Char String }` then? (Using [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map.html) from the [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) library if you haven’t encountered it before. A simpler alternative would be `[(Char,String)]`, but `containers` has more functionality.)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome @timothyylim! Should I add that as an answer?

Comment: yes please, @bradrn!

Comment: One more comment: in his answer, @fredefox has used the `URI` type instead of plain `String`. That might be a good idea if you are specifically storing URLs, as opposed to my answer which is a bit less specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems that one `request` in your configuration can contain any number of key-value pairs, where the keys and values are both strings. Accordingly, a good choice for your configuration would be a [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) or [`HashMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.10.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html). `Map` is generally more popular (although I could be wrong), but the `yaml` library [uses `HashMap` to represent objects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.11.1.1/docs/Data-Yaml.html#t:Object), and based on [this](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/05/weigh-package#containers-vs-unordered-containers) `HashMap` appears to be more memory-efficient. If you want, you can additionally wrap your map in an additional data type for extra type safety, so something like `newtype Config = Config { getConfig :: Map String String }`.

(Or you could just use a list of key-value pairs `[(String, String)]`, but `yaml` depends on both `containers` and `unordered-containers` anyway so you might as well use their functionality!)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
data Config where
  request :: Request -> Config

newtype Request = Request (HashMap Text URI)
```

`HashMap` has the following instance: `FromJSON v => FromJSON (HashMap Text v)` So you can easily define `FromJSON` for this type using `-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and similarly for `ToJSON`.